# Gcm with appodeal

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, prime31

I am using gcm with appodeal in my app and when I am sending the push notification the for the first push was successful but phone is not receiving the notification and after that error is there while sending push that device is not register. What to do in this situation please help me.

Comment: Please have a look at [hot to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You can also find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) useful.

Answer (score 0):

Is it iOS or Android ? I had the exact same issue just yesterday with iOS and all I had to was to create a development provisioning profile and set it up properly in xCode. I hope that helps you.

Comment: I am facing problem in android. Thanks for comment

Answer (score 0):

I think for you to verify that your app can send and receive messages, [client apps must register with GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration).

To register with GCM:

1.The client app obtains a registration token using the Instance ID API. The call to this API must have the authorized entity set to your app server's sender ID, and the scope set to the appropriate value for GCM (depending on your platform). Refer to the API reference for full detail on this API.

2.The client app passes the registration token to the app server.
3. The app server saves the registration token and acknowledges to the client app that the process completed successfully.

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33546279/android-gcm-not-registered-though-getregistrationid-returns-an-id) may also provide further insight as to why you are receiving the device not registered error.